# Menu changes its placement (position) when moving between different submenus

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, menu

I used Miracle Wordpress Theme for creating our website.
I have used plugin Max Mega Menu wordpress plugin for configure my main-menu.
Everything is working fine as per our requirement, but issue is when i click on sub-menus of Main menu at that time i fill the menu tabs are little bit changes their position.

Refer our website link: http://www.autonebula.com/

I mean when i gone through sub menus,look at each pages the menu bar(tabs) are little bit changes their position.

Why this happen, i want Main menu that do not change their position in all pages when i click on sub menus.

Please suggest me the proper way.

Comment: Sorry but i dont think i understand your problem.. it seems fine to me

Comment: I do not see the problem either... Everything seems to be fine. What browser are you using?

Comment: I have used chrome browser, open all the pages in different tabs and look carefully on each pages, the main menu tabs moves little bit left or right side(change their placement)

Comment: Sorry man, but i tried it again, and everything seems in place and does not move a pixel left or right on my chrome browser, by the way on mobile version, your footer takes too much space, i recomend you removing the sticky value of your footer